# CoreData throws warning that class for entity could not be loaded

Tags: objective-c, macos, core-data, xcode6

I'm writing an OS X Command Line tool in Objective-C which uses a CoreData model from an external framework. This framework defines each class for the core data model. Header files are referenced in my project by including the archived framework. But I still get a warning when creating an `NSEntityDescription` which is casted to the specific `NSManagedObject` class:

```
Klass entity = (Klass *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Klass" inManagedObjectContext:context];
```

Xcode throws the following warning when executing the code above:

```
CoreData: warning: Unable to load class named 'Klass' for entity 'Klass'.  Class not found, using default NSManagedObject instead.
```

I searched for a solution but was not able to find and solve my problem. I tried to namespace the entities in the model. But this was not working.

I hope you can help me.

Comment: Please show your Klass.h and Klass.m (is that the real name?) are they included in the target? Can you add a screenshot maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve my problem. Initially I tried to create a new Entity and casted it to the specific `NSManagedObject` class.

```
SpecificManagedObjectClass *managedObject = (SpecificManagedObjectClass *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"SpecificManagedObjectClass" inManagedObjectContext:context];
```

Now the solution for my specific problem is the following:

```
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:[SpecificManagedObjectClass className] inManagedObjectContext:context];
SpecificManagedObjectClass *managedObject = [[SpecificManagedObjectClass alloc] initWithEntity:entity insertIntoManagedObjectContext:context];
```

Thus I wrote a helper method:

```
- (id)getManagedObjectInstanceFor:(id)managedObject in:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context {
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:[managedObject className] inManagedObjectContext:context];
    return [[[managedObject class] alloc] initWithEntity:entity insertIntoManagedObjectContext:context];
}
```

This results in the following call:

```
SpecificManagedObjectClass *managedObject = [[Utils sharedInstance] getManagedObjectInstanceFor: SpecificManagedObjectClass.class in:self.managedObjectContext];
```

Which gives me an instance of the specific `NSManagedObject` class.